# Unity 3D with Vuforia AR: Adding a Gameobject to ARCamera View

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, vuforia

I am using Unity3D with extension of Vuforia. I am working on Cylindrical targets. When `ARCamera` detects the image and starts the augmentation, I want to show my `GameObject` (`.fbx` file, imported into the Meshes folder and created a Prefab out of it) on the screen. 
I am working in Unity C#.

I attached a script to the `GameObject` and initialized it `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` Script. When I run it in Unity and the camera starts, I don't see my object in the Game View. Whereas in Screen View, I see that bottle (Prefab) rotating.

Answer (score 2):

make sure the camera, or the focal point has your object in sight, when i tried vuforia, rotate your card slowly 360° to see if you can see the object, also your object could be far above what you expect, I would recommend very long expanded cubes in the 3 axis, to get the reference in the augmented world, then move from there

Comment: Thank you for the response Poncho. I guess you are right about that prefab being far too above my expectations. I just have to use this object once so I think I shouldnt make it a Prefab, right? Secondly, when I play it in Unity. I see (in Scene View) a clone of that bottle far upward rotating which means that my script is working on that clone.
The main problem I have been facing is that When I zoom to my bottle Prefab and align my  "ARCamera" to the View I don't see anything in the Camera/Game View.

Comment: long time since i used vuforia, but i think that when you lost sight of your card, the view of the game, is suspended, check if when you align your camera to your bottle, the card still on sight, or try moving the bottle closer to the card to avoid that.

Comment: What I did was removed/deleted the ARCamera and bottle from the scene and introduced them again and did all the settings. And it worked Viola !!! Thanks for your ideas Poncho. :)

Comment: hahahaha, have you tried turning it off and on again ? (IT crowd), great it worked, good luck